# Normal space and regular space

Tags: general-topology

1) Let $X$ be a regular space with a countable base. Let $U$ be an open set in $X$.

Show that $U$ equals a countable union of closed sets of $X$.

Please help me !

Answer (score 0):

Let $B_n, n \in \Bbb N$ be a countable base for $X$.

Then by regularity $$U=\bigcup \{\overline{B_n}: \overline{B_n} \subseteq U\}$$

so $U$ is an at most countable union of closed sets.

(If $x \in U$, for some $O$ open we have $x \in O \subseteq \overline{O} \subseteq U$ by regularity of $X$. Then for some $n$: $x \in B_n \subseteq O$ as the $B_n$ form a base. It follows that $x \in \overline{B_n}$ which is part of the right hand union. If OTOH $x$ is in the right hand union, it's in some $\overline{B_n}$ that by definition (!) is a subset of $U$ so that $x \in U$ as well. Two inclusions, hence equality of sets.)

Comment: what do you mean by (!) this

Comment: @SushantaDas nota bene, take attention..

Answer (score 0):

Let $(B_i)$ be a countable basis. Let $x \in U$. Then (by regularity)  there exist an open set $V_x$ such that $x \in V_x $ and $\overline {V_x} \subseteq U$. There exist $i_x$ such that $x \in B_{i_x} \subseteq  V_x$. Now verify that $U$ is the union of the closed sets $\overline {B_{i_x}}$.

Comment: unnecessary use of choice :)